# embedded form relations with doctrine

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I currently using ahDoctrineEasyEmbeddedRelationsPlugin to embed a Block form into a Page form.

All works well, but I'd like to hide the label of the embeddedRelation.

I've created a 'homepage-main-top' Block within the Page form in the admin, now when editting this Page, I now see 'homepage-main-top' is randomly appearing before the embedded block relation

Looking at the plugin docs, there doesn't seem to be anything relating to removing/hiding this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/197/relation.png

Does anyone know how to not display this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggeling with somewhat the same problem, only I needed to style the label instead of hidding / stripping it.

From what I've found out there is no simple way to manipulate the label of the embedded form, but I figured the following 'hack'.

The embedRelation method accepts a inner- and outer-decorator parameter. You can use these to wrap extra markup around the label and the embedded form. You can then use CSS to hide the label using a specific id / css class.

By openning tags in the outerdecorator and closing them in the inner decorator you can wrap the label in a tag (which is rendered inbetween the two). It is kind of tricky to make sure your HTML is still valid.

I know this is kind of a crappy solution but I haven't found a better way up until now.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your parent form:

```
$this->widgetSchema['EmbeddedFormName']->setLabel(' ');
```

If the above doesn't work, try using the 'newFormLabel' option (from the plugin's documentation).

```
$this->embedRelations(array(
    'RelationName' => array(
    // ...
      'newFormLabel'  => ' ',
    // ...
    ),
    // ...
  ));
```

Comment: Try using the 'newFormLabel' option for the plugin. I've updated my comments.